# Can I impose restrictions in Google Chrome or Firefox?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, firefox-extensions, google-chrome-extensions

Let me explain. I am an IT person in a small office. We have recently got new desktops and I installed Google Chrome and Firefox browsers on them. There's one catch -- I need to be able to control what plug-ins are installed in those browsers. The people who will be using these desktops are mostly middle-aged women that will not be trying to hack into these systems, I just need to safeguard against installation of all the " accidental web junk". Like, for instance, I come in today look at one desktop and there's a huge Yahoo BHO bar in Firefox. I asked who installed it and they all said that they didn't do it :) So I need to guard against these kind of "dummy" installations, but unfortunately I can't seem to find any way to do it in Chrome or FF.

So don't tell me that my only option is to use IE and Group Policy objects?

Comment: Chrome and Firefox both will block these installations by default soon.

Comment: @Sathya: What are you basing it on?

Comment: chrome dev channel already has this feature.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there *[might](http://forums.comodo.com/news-announcements-feedback-cis/how-to-block-firefox-extension-installs-with-cis-t41615.0.html)* (see Reply #6) be a way to do this. You could give it a go.

Alternatively, you could implement something like [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/) to wrap up the FF installation and prevent changes.

Comment: Thanks. It sounds too complicated. I wish Google and FF realized the need for this kinda feature and added it already.

Comment: True. Though, speaking as an enterprise user with a locked down IE, it's *great* being able to install plugins on FireFox! ;)